# Calling a WebAPI from client side through POST method fails

Tags: ajax, json, post, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to call a web-api from client side. The web api contains a Request class with Amount as decimal. We are trying to pass a decimal amount and getting back the same amount in response from webapi along with the status.

The problem is that *the web-api is not able to receive the amount.*  When we try to attach with webapi we see only `null` in the Amount field in the Request class.
Any help in this regard would be great.

Below is how we call from client side

```
    var requestMessage = { RequestSale: { Amount: '100.545M' } };        
    var request = {
        type: "POST",            
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "http://<machinename>/Demo/api/monthlySales/InsertMonthlySales",
        successCallback: successCallback,
        errorCallback: errorCallback,
        filterCriteria: null,            
        data: JSON.stringify(requestMessage)
        //header: { key: "Accept", value: "application/json" },
    };

    utilityTest.getData(request);
    expect(true, true);
```

---

utilityTest.getData(request) -- This makes the actual call, below is code

```
 utilityTest.getData = function (request) {
    $.ajax({
        type: request.type,
        contentType: request.contentType,
        datatype: request.datatype,
        url: request.url,
        data: request.data,
        cache : false,
        beforeSend: function (xmlHttpRequest) {            
                if (request.header) {
                    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(request.header.key, request.header.value);
                }                            
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) {
            if (request.successCallback) {
                request.successCallback(data, request.filterCriteria);
            }
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (request.errorCallback)
                request.errorCallback(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }    });
```

### }

Web-api method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ResponseSale InsertMonthlySales(RequestSale sale)
        {
            var curMonth = DateTime.UtcNow.Month;
            var salesAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(sale.Amount);
            ResponseSale response = new ResponseSale();
            response.Amount = salesAmount;
            response.Id = curMonth;

            if (monthlySales.ContainsKey(curMonth))
            {
                monthlySales[curMonth] += salesAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                monthlySales.Add(curMonth, salesAmount);
            }
            response.Status = "InsertMonthlySales";
            return response;
```

### }

Request/Response contract for web-api

```
namespace DemoContracts.Object
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://DemoSchema.ContractSale")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://DemoSchema.ContractSale", IsNullable = false)]  
    public class RequestSale {           
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }          
    }
}

namespace DemoContracts.Object
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://DemoSchema.ContractSale")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://DemoSchema.ContractSale", IsNullable = false)]
    public class ResponseSale
    {        
        public string Status { get; set; }     
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }        
        public int Id { get; set; }        
    }
```

### }

--JSON as captured from IE
Request Body :
{"RequestSale":{"Amount":100.545}}

Response Body
{"Status":"InsertMonthlySales","Amount":0.0,"Id":9}

In Web API, InsertMonthSales request object RequestSale.Amount is always be 0. We are not getting the passed 100.545 value

Comment: What is `utilityTest`?

Comment: Post the json output your sending, from fiddler or similar, and your object that is in your web api recieving the input or the whole method even

Comment: sorry I am editing my post for the giving further details Alex

Comment: Saj and tyme JV,  I have updated the edits, as requested by you